# Can monsters of real analysis be tamed in this way?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, continuity, fractals

Consider the [Weierstrass Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassFunction.html) (somewhat generalized for arbitrary wavelengths $\,\lambda > 0$ ):
$$
W(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\left(n^2\,2\pi/\lambda\,x\right)}{n^2}
$$
$W(x)$ is an example of a function that is everywhere continuous but nowhere differentiable (Or, for the nitpickers among us: differentiable only on a set of points of measure zero). We seek to remove the pathological character of the function $W(x)$ in  very much the same way as has been tried with removing singularities in  
[Could this be called Renormalization?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781281/could-this-be-called-renormalization) ,
namely by convolution with a "broadened" Dirac-Delta function, in our case a Gaussian:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{^\infty} W(\xi) \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\xi)^2/\sigma^2}\,d\xi =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{^\infty}
\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\xi)^2/\sigma^2}\left[e^{i\,n^2\,2\pi/\lambda\,\xi}-e^{-i\,n^2\,2\pi/\lambda\,\xi}\right]}{2\,i\,n^2}
$$
Exponents are rewritten as follows:
$$
-\frac{1}{2}(x-\xi)^2/\sigma^2 \pm i\,n^2\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\xi =
- \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\xi}{\sigma}\right)^2 + \frac{x}{\sigma}\frac{\xi}{\sigma}
\pm i\,n^2\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\sigma\frac{\xi}{\sigma} - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right)^2 =
-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\xi}{\sigma}-\left(\frac{x}{\sigma} \pm i\,n^2\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\sigma\right)\right]^2
-\frac{1}{2}\left(n^2\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\sigma\right)^2 \pm i\,n^2\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}x
$$
Giving for the convolution integral:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty
\int_{-\infty}^{^\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left[\xi/\sigma-(x/\sigma \pm i\,n^2\,2\pi/\lambda\,\sigma)\right]^2}\,d(\xi/\sigma)\times\sigma\times\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\;(=1)\\
\times e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(n^2\,2\pi/\lambda\,\sigma\right)^2}\frac{e^{i\,n^2\,2\pi/\lambda\,x} - e^{-i\,n^2\,2\pi/\lambda\,x}}{2i\,n^2}\qquad \Longrightarrow \\ \overline{W}(x) =
\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(n^2\,2\pi/\lambda\,\sigma\right)^2}\frac{\sin\left(n^2\,2\pi/\lambda\,x\right)}{n^2}
$$
The idea is that a monster function which is "smoothed" in this way might be differentiable as well as continuous. A possible argument is that the derivative of the convolution integral can also be calculated in the following way:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_{-\infty}^{^\infty} W(\xi) \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\xi)^2/\sigma^2}\,d\xi =
\int_{-\infty}^{^\infty} W(\xi) \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \left(-\frac{x-\xi}{\sigma^2}\right) e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\xi)^2/\sigma^2}\,d\xi
$$
But I'm not sure if this counts as a proof. Hence the question: is the Weierstrass monster function "tamed" by this "renormalization" procedure and has it become differentiable everywhere indeed?

Comment: Is there any claim about the magnitude of $|W(x)-\overline W(x)|$?

Comment: The convolution always copies the differentiability properties of the "better" function, i.e. if $f$ is smooth and $g$ is say, only continuous, then $f*g$ is smooth. Put $f$ to be your Weierstrass function and $g$ the Gaussian. The proof goes like you started but there is no need to write down these monstrous formulas, just take $f$, $g$ arbitrary. Whats missing in your argument is why you can take the differential under the integral.

Comment: @YourAdHere: (+1) for your comment. But alas, if I could fill in the  "missing" parts and thus answer my own question, then I wouldn't have asked for an another answer.

Comment: Your Ad Here's suggestion works fine. Alternatively, $\overline{W}\in C^{\infty}$ also follows from the fact that if you differentiate the new series term by term (any number of times), you obtain another uniformly and absolutely convergent series.

Comment: @Han de Bruijn: This is one of the most fundamental properties of the convolution operation. You should find it discussed in any analysis textbook that covers convolution or Fourier analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we have:
$$\overline{W}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{-An^2}\frac{\sin(Bn^2 x)}{n^2}$$
it follows that:
$$\overline{W}(x)-\overline{W}(y)=\sum_{n=1}^{M}e^{-An^2}\frac{\sin(Bn^2 x)-\sin(Bn^2 y)}{n^2}+O(e^{-AM^2}(x-y)),$$
so by assuming $|x-y|\leq\frac{1}{M^2}$ and exploiting the Lipschitz condition for the sine function:
$$\left|\frac{\overline{W}(x)-\overline{W}(y)}{x-y}\right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{M}B e^{-An^2}+O(e^{-AM^2})=O(1),$$
hence the smoothed Weierstrass function is a Lipschitz function, and
$$\overline{W}'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}Be^{-An^2}\cos(Bn^2 x)$$
since the RHS is an absolutely convergent series. Iterating the same argument over and over we have that $\overline{W}$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function, since the sine and cosine function are always bounded and the coefficients $B^k n^{2k}e^{-An^2}$ decay pretty fast as soon as $n$ is big enough.