# Can every continuous function be continuously ''transformed'' into a differentiable function?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

> Can every continuous function $f(x)$ from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously "transformed" into a differentiable function?

More precisely is  there always  a continuous (non constant) $g(x)$ such that $g(f(x))$ is differentiable?

- This seems to hold for simple functions, for instance the function $f(x)=|x|$ can be transformed into a differentiable function by the function $g(x)=x^2$.
- If $g(x)$ is additionally required to be increasing everywhere and
  differentiable then the answer seems to be ***no*** by the inverse
  function theorem, because of the existence of continuous nowhere
  differentiable functions.

Comment: Relevant: [*On transformations of derivatives*](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1975-048-01/S0002-9939-1975-0360950-7/) (1975) AND [*Differentiability through change of variables*](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-061-02/S0002-9939-1976-0432831-2/) (1976) AND [*Creating differentiability and destroying derivatives*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2320863) (1978), all 3 by Andrew M. Bruckner.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Sadly they only talk about homeomorphisms , I also looked in Bruckners derivatives book but could find anything there

Comment: I don't really know anything about this topic, but I did know that Bruckner (and some others) had worked on it. I thought maybe the papers themselves, or their references, or items that cite these papers (those that you can find by googling) would have something useful for you, but I don't know enough to easily investigate this myself.

Comment: Related: [Can monsters of real analysis be tamed in this way?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804117/can-monsters-of-real-analysis-be-tamed-in-this-way)

Comment: Introducing "new" concepts in mathematics such as "corners", "flat" and "infinite composition" is not without risk: unexpected side effects are lurking around the corner.
If your only objective is to "make" everywhere continuous / nowhere differentiable functions everywhere differentiable, then a pretty standard technique
like [Gaussian blur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) (one-dimensional equivalent) certainly is preferrable. I have posted an answer along
these lines, but clearly it is not appreciated, so I deleted it.

Comment: @HandeBruijn I am not sure what you mean by "unexpected side effects are lurking around the corner" .

Comment: Such as: with infinite composition I can “prove” that the naturals do not exist. Believe it or not.

Comment: @HandeBruijn: Only if you pretend that your infinite composition tends to a limit without verifying it's true, I'm sure.

Comment: @Troposphere: Define “true”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by [Frank's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4157185/907303) notion of "corner", let's define

- The function $f$ has a **"flat"** at $x$ iff for every $\delta>0$ there is an $x_1$ with $0<|x-x_1|<\delta$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x)$. (In other words, $x$ is a limit point of the fiber of $f$ it's a member of).

One easily proves:

1. If $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and has a flat at $x$, then $f'(x)=0$.
2. The points where $f$ has flats depend only on the set of fibers of $f$ -- or, in other words, on the equivalence relation $x\sim_f y \Leftrightarrow f(x)=f(y)$.
3. If $f$ has a flat at $x$ and $g$ is an *arbitrary* function, then $g\circ f$ also has a flat at $x$.

I will construct a continuous surjection $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ where every $x$ is flat (that is, in more dignified terms, a function whose fibers are all perfect sets). This property guarantees that $g\circ f$ can only be differentiable if it is constant.

---

First, let $w:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a zig-zag function that goes from $0$ up to $1$, then down to $0$ and back up to $1$:

$$ w(x) = \begin{cases}
3x & 0 \le x \le 1/3 \\
2 - 3x & 1/3 \le x \le 2/3 \\
3x - 2 & 2/3 \le x \le 1 \end{cases} $$

Stack an infinite sequence of $w$s to get $u:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$:
$$ u(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor + w\bigl(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\bigr) $$
We note that $u$ is continuous and $|u(x)-x|<1$ everywhere.

Now for each $n\ge 0$, let
$$ h_n(x) = \frac{u(2^n x)}{2^n} $$
This looks like $u$, except that we have "zoomed out" by a factor of $2^n$ so we have more and smaller wiggles around $x=y$. In particular, $|h_n(x)-x|\le 2^{-n}$.

Now form the *infinite composition* of all the $h_n$'s:
$$ f = \lim_{n\to\infty} h_n \circ h_{n-1} \circ \cdots \circ h_1 \circ h_0 $$
or, written in more detail:
$$ f_0(x) = x \qquad\qquad f_{n+1}(x) = h_n(f_n(x)) \qquad\qquad f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) $$
The limit exists pointwise because the bound on the wiggles on each $h_n$ makes the sequence Cauchy -- and this argument actually bounds the difference *uniformly*. So $f$ is *continuous*, being a uniform limit of continuous functions.

---

To see that $f$ has flats everywhere, it is convenient to define
$$ k_n(x) = 2^n f_n(x) $$
We then have the recurrence
$$ k_0(x) = x \qquad\qquad k_n(x) = 2u(k_{n-1}(x)) $$
In other words, we're just iterating $2u$. We don't need to worry about taking the limit anymore, because the fibers of the $k_n$s (and therefore also of $f_n$) will tell us enough to conclude that $f$ has flats everywhere.

Note that $k_n$ is piecewise linear, with each linear piece having slope $\pm 6^n$, and it changes direction only at points where $k_n(x)$ is an (even) integer.

Now suppose we're given $x$ and we're looking for a $x_1$ within $\delta=6^{-n}$ of $x$ where $f(x_1)=f(x)$. We fast-forward to $k_n$ and find that $x$ lies in a closed interval $[y,y+6^{-n}]$ where $k_n(x)$ either ascends linearly from an integer to the next or descends from an integer to the previous (namely, $y=6^{-n}\lfloor 6^n x\rfloor$ will work). This means that $k_{n+1}$ restricted to this interval attains each value in its image at least twice. So we can find an $x_1\ne x$ in the interval such that $k_{n+1}(x_1) = k_{n+1}(x)$ and therefore also $f(x_1)=f(x)$, as required.

Comment: (I'm fairly sure one could also set $u(x) = x + \alpha \sin(2\pi x)$, with $\alpha\approx 0.73264413$ chosen so the local minimum near $x=0.715$ is exactly $0$. That would make the $f_n$s (but not $f$, of course) nice and smooth -- but it would also make it more complicated to be sure that there's always a $k_n$ whose wiggles are narrow enough to fit into a $\delta$.)

Comment: What was the motivation for taking the infinite composition ?

Comment: @PaxDaga: Umm, that I can prove it works? In particular, it's a way to add more wiggles that's guaranteeed to preserve already-established $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ relations, which would'n't be the case if I _added_ new wiggles (like in the Weierstrass function).

Comment: With hindsight, you could say that I'm trying to give the function a property that says "no matter which $g$ we compose on the left, such-and-such will be true". Thus when my construction takes multiple steps, combining the steps by _composition_ instead of addition naturally means that later steps will not ruin the parts of the property I've already achieved.

Comment: I don't understand why the filers of $f_{n}$ give the filers of f ?

Comment: @PaxDaga: If you have $f_n(x)=f_n(y)$, then by definition of the $f_n$s you also have $f_{n+1}(x)=f_{n+1}(y)$, and $f_{n+2}(x)=f_{n+2}(y)$, and so on. This means that the sequences $f_1(x), f_2(x), f_3(y) \ldots$ and $f_1(y), f_2(y), f_3(y), \ldots$ that define the pointwise limits are _identical from step $n$ onwards_, and therefore their limits are the same -- in other words, $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: To be sure, we don't get _all_ equalities between $f(x)$s  that way (or in other words, we don't get _full_ knowledge of the fibers of $f$). As one example: $k_n(\frac15) = 2^n-\frac45$ (becasue $2w(\frac15)=1+\frac15$) so $f_n(\frac15)= 1 - 2^{-n}\frac45$, and $f_m(1)=1$ for all $n$, so $f(\frac15)=f(1)=1$, but there's no $n$ where $f(\frac15)=f(1)$. But that's not a problem; all that matters for us here is that we discover _enough_ of the $(x,y)$ pairs where $f(x)=f(y)$ to conclude that $f$ has flats everywhere.

Comment: (Above comment should have said "there's no _n_ where $f_n(\frac15)=f_n(1)$").

Comment: I think there is a continuous function with 0’s on all rationals that should be another counter example ?

Comment: @PaxDaga: Do you mean a continuous function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(q)=0$ for every $q\in\mathbb Q$? The only such function is the constant zero function, not much of a counterexample :-)

Comment: Interesting! To plot some function, you could use this link: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ys9nuafdq0 . The $f_n$ iterated would be cool to have, but I am not familiar with Desmos. But with these graphs, most of his arguments is easy to follow.

Answer (score 6):

*Edit 1.* I realized my proof has a mistake. Because I use the inverse function theorem on $g \circ f$, my answer only checks out if $g \circ f$ is required to be *continuously differentiable*.

---

*Original answer.* Here's a counterexample.

We say a function $f$ is **locally injective** at a point $x$ if there exists a small interval $(x - \delta, x + \delta)$ where $x$ is injective. Suppose we have a function $f$ that is *not* locally injective at a point $x$. Also, suppose we have a function $g$ where the composition $g \circ f$ is differentiable at $x$. Note that because $f$ is not locally injective at $x$, $g \circ f$ cannot be locally injective by $x$. So by the inverse function theorem, its derivative $(g \circ f)'$ must necessarily vanish at $x$. This leads us to the following question:

**Question.** Can we find a function that is everywhere continuous, but *nowhere locally injective*?

If we can find such a function $f$, then any composition $g \circ f$ must be have an identically zero derivative. This means $g \circ f$ must be constant, implying $g$ is constant (at least in the range of $f$)!

We can achieve this with a function $f$ that is everywhere continuous, but nowhere differentiable. There are many such functions, the most famous being the “pathological” [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function). To prove $f$ is nowhere locally injective, suppose toward a contradiction that it is locally injective at a point $x$. Then there is in a small interval $I$ about $x$ where $f$ is injective and continuous, and hence monotone. By Lebesgue's monotone function theorem referenced in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853639/a-continuous-nowhere-differentiable-but-invertible-function), $f$ must be differentiable almost everywhere in $I$. This is a contradiction because $f$ is nowhere differentiable.

---

*Edit 2.* Instead of examining local injectivity, we can maybe examine a slightly stronger condition. Let's say a function $f$ has a **corner** (not an actual term) at a point $x$ if for all $\delta > 0$, there exists $x_1, x_2 \in (x - \delta, x + \delta)$ such that $x_1 < x < x_2$ and $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. The key here is that a “corner” requires the points breaking injectivity to lie on both sides of $x$.

We can show that if $f$ has a corner at $x$ and $g \circ f$ is differentiable at $x$, then $(g \circ f)'$ must vanish at $x$. For all $\delta > 0$, let $x_{1, \delta} < x < x_{2, \delta}$ be as in the definition of a corner. Taking the left-side points, we get
$$
\tag{1}
(g \circ f)'(x) = \lim_{\delta \to 0^+}
\frac{(g \circ f)(x_{1, \delta}) - (g \circ f)(x)}
{x_{1, \delta} - x},
$$
and taking the right-side points, we get
$$
\tag{2}
(g \circ f)'(x) =
\lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \frac{(g \circ f)(x_{2, \delta}) - (g \circ f)(x)}
{x_{2, \delta} - x}.
$$
Note that the numerators of $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equal because $(g \circ f)(x_{1, \delta}) = (g \circ f)(x_{2, \delta})$. However, the denominators $x_{1, \delta} - x$ and $x_{2, \delta} - x$ have opposite signs, so we must have $(g \circ f)'(x) = 0$. Therefore, we can instead ask the question:

**Question.**  Can we find a function that is everywhere continuous, but has a corner at every point in $\mathbb{R}$?

Because the Weierstrass function behaves like a fractal, this seems like it would be true (but maybe it only has corners densely packed in $\mathbb{R}$, in which continuous differentiability comes back to bite us). I'm not sure how to prove this though.

Comment: If $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, then $g(f(x_1)) = g(f(x_2))$. So if $f$ is not locally injective at $x$, then we can find points $x_1, x_2$ arbitrarily close to $x$ where $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. Then $g(f(x_1)) = g(f(x_2))$, which implies $g \circ f$ is not locally injective.

Comment: Yeah, that was my intuition.

Comment: If you're referring to equation (1), note that $\delta$ is always positive.

Comment: Inspired by this answer, I found a different stronger form of "nowhere locally injective" which let me construct an explicit counterexample.

Answer (score 4):

Gillis, Note on a conjecture of Erdos, Quart. J. of Math.,Oxford 10, (1939),151-154, has an example of a continuous function $f$, all of whose level sets are Cantor sets. Unless $g$ is a constant function, it seems $g \circ f$ won't be differentiable.
(Gillis made other claims that were false, but his function does have every level set being a Cantor set).

Foran also has an example, but I don't think he published it. He constructs its graph as the intersection of a nested sequence of rectangles in the unit square.